# Коды мультимедийных клавиш

Tags: c#

Кто знает коды мультимедийных клавиш для sendkey, клавиши типа стоп, играть, прибавить звук, убавить, mute, нигде не смог найти.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите управлять проигрывателем Windows Media, то существует описание управляющих клавиш для него: [сочетания клавиш в проигрывателе Windows Media](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-vista/Windows-Media-Player-keyboard-shortcuts). Если интересует список виртуальных клавиш, он также есть на сайте MSDN: [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Конкретно, это коды вида `VK_MEDIA_XXX`, `VK_VOLUME_XXX`.